# How to automatically submit a form if all fields are filled in jQuery without using each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a OTP form which I want to submit via AJAX if all it's input fields are filled in. Is it possible with using class selector `$(".tp")`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tp").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == 1) {
    // this will automatically change the focus as soon as an input is done
      $(this).next().focus() 
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this without an explicit loop you can use `filter()` to find all fields which do not have a value. If there aren't any, then you know you are safe to make your AJAX request. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $tp = $(".tp").on('input', e => {
    if (e.target.value.length == 1) {
      $(e.target).next().focus();
    }

    if ($tp.filter((i, el) => !el.value.trim()).length == 0) {
      console.log('AJAX call goes here...');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {   
  width: 15px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
<input type="tel" class="tp" maxlength="1">
```